# Canvas JS mouseover create circle

Tags: javascript, canvas, mouseover

Goodmorning everyone.
I have a canvas with an image, I capture the color on mouse over and if the color is different from white, I change the mouse pointer, now I would like others to change the pointer, could create a circle of size 24x24px following the mouse. I created this photo for example

[image]

Can you help me? 
thank

```
$('#canvas').mousemove(function(event) {
    var pos = findPos(this);
    var dimensionMarker = 12;
    x_default = event.pageX - pos.x;
    y_default = event.pageY - pos.y;
    x = (event.pageX - pos.x) - dimensionMarker;
    y = (event.pageY - pos.y) - dimensionMarker;
    var coord = "x=" + x_default + ", y=" + y_default;
    var c = this.getContext('2d');
    var p = c.getImageData(x_default, y_default, 1, 1).data; 
    hex = "#" + ("000000" + rgbToHex(p[0], p[1], p[2])).slice(-6);
    if(hex != "#ffffff"){
        $(this).css({cursor: 'pointer'});
    }else{
        $(this).css({cursor: 'default'});
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a bit dirty trick from my [notator test](https://unespiedtouch.htmlpasta.com/) made something in SVG.

```js
$('#paintArea').mousemove(function(event) {
    x_default = event.pageX;
    y_default = event.pageY;
    var c = $('#canvas')[0].getContext('2d');
    var p = c.getImageData(x_default, y_default, 1, 1).data;
    hex = "#" + ("000000" + rgbToHex(p[0], p[1], p[2])).slice(-6);
    if(hex != "#ffffff"){
        paintArea.firstElementChild.style.display = "none";
        $(this).css({cursor: 'pointer'});
    }else{
        showPos(event.originalEvent);
        paintArea.firstElementChild.style.display = "";
        $(this).css({cursor: 'default'});
    }
    window.status = hex;
});

var cursor;
var paintArea = document.getElementById("paintArea");
function showPos(e) {
 var info;
 paintArea.firstElementChild.setAttribute('transform', 'translate(' + e.x + ',' + e.y + ')');
}

// env preparation
function rgbToHex(r,g,b) {
    hex = (0x1000000 + (r << 16) + (g << 8) + b).toString(16).slice(1);
    return hex;
}

var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
const img = new Image()
img.src = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAOEAAACWAQAAAAAA79KuAAAACXBIWXMAAAsSAAALEgHS3X78AAAAOUlEQVRYhe3JMQ0AIAwAwSYIwSpSEUICC2VCQIf78S8i6/u24hOllFJKaUHNt2ee9taglFJKKa2sB2rwUcX1FaqwAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC"
img.onload = function () {
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0)
}

// Load and convert IMG 2 data URI
function zobrazit(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            var obrazek = document.getElementById("obrazek");
            obrazek.src = e.target.result;
            document.forms[0].dataUri.value = obrazek.src;
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px blue;
  background-color: gray;
}
svg {
  border: 1px green;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg id="paintArea">
  <circle cx="0" cy="0" r="24" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
</svg>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>

<form style="float:right">
    <input
        type='file'
        onchange="zobrazit(this)"
    size=60>
    <br>
    <textarea name=dataUri rows=10 cols=40></textarea>
</form>
<img id="obrazek">
```

Comment: Works - thought it is a color problem, but looks like security picture should come from same source (did not work on local with img on server for example). When same https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/28/Sillitoe-black-white.gif picture is converted to data uri it works...

Comment: Error message when not inlined: Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'getImageData' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The canvas has been tainted by cross-origin data.

Answer (score 0):

If canvas is image not working return always #00000 color

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('#canvas');
            var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
            var imageObj = new Image();
            imageObj.src = urlImg;
            imageObj.onload = function () {
                context.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0);
            };
```